# Google Maps API v3 problems on IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-maps-api-3

Hi I have a website that uses Google Maps API v3 for members locations.

But with Internet Explorer I have a couple of issues:

*1.-* When the website loads the javascript it throws an errror (only on IE):_

```
Message: Invalid property value.
Line: 33
Char: 212
Code: 0
URI: http://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/en_gb/mapfiles/api-3/4/7/%7Bmain,geometry%7D.js
```

This is the JS I'm loading:
**http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&sensor=true**

This is the last part of that file (the part that cause the problem):

```
[...]
var loadScriptTime = (new Date).getTime();
getScript("http://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/en_gb/mapfiles/api-3/4/7/%7Bmain,geometry%7D.js");
})();
```

*2.-* The map loads and shows the correct position but it doesn't show any controls and is not possible to interact with the map (this is probably because of the first error)

Does anybody know how to fix that?

Thanks!

EDIT --------------------------

Here are the functions I use to load the map:

```
function initialize() {

    london = new google.maps.LatLng(51.5, 0);
    uk = new google.maps.LatLng(55.7, -4 );

    var myOptions = {
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFF',
        zoom: 12,
        navigationControl: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map_canvas = document.getElementById("map_canvas");

    map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, myOptions);


    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mouseover', function(event) {
        $(map_canvas).ancestors()[0].addClassName("bigGMap");
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mouseout', function(event) {
        $(map_canvas).ancestors()[0].removeClassName("bigGMap");
    });


    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'click', function(event) {
        placeMarker(event.latLng);
    });

    getMyLocation();


}

function getMyLocation()
{
    // Try W3C Geolocation (Preferred)
    if(navigator.geolocation) {
        browserSupportFlag = true;
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
          initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
          map.setCenter(initialLocation);
        }, function() {
          handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
        });
        // Try Google Gears Geolocation
    } else if (google.gears) {
        browserSupportFlag = true;
        var geo = google.gears.factory.create('beta.geolocation');
        geo.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
          initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.latitude,position.longitude);
          map.setCenter(initialLocation);
        }, function() {
          handleNoGeoLocation(browserSupportFlag);
        });
        // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    } else
    {
        browserSupportFlag = false;
        handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
    }

}

function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
    map.setZoom(6),
    map.setCenter(uk);
    map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP);
}


function loadMapScript() {
  var map_api = document.createElement("script");
  var gears = document.createElement("script");

  map_api.type = "text/javascript";
  map_api.src = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&sensor=true&callback=initialize";

  gears.type = "text/javascript";
  gears.src = "http://code.google.com/apis/gears/gears_init.js";

  document.body.appendChild(map_api);
  document.body.appendChild(gears);
}
```

Comment: Even though the error shows in the google code, the problem is very likely to be in your page when initializing the map. Can you show that code, too?

Comment: @Pekka I just added the functions I use to load the map.

Comment: are you using prototype as your JS Framework?

Comment: @kjy112 yes, I'm using Prototype. Is that the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I finally found the problem. It's in the **initialize** function

```
function initialize() {

    london = new google.maps.LatLng(51.5, 0);
    uk = new google.maps.LatLng(55.7, -4 );


    var myOptions = {
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF ',
        zoom: 12,
        navigationControl: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    [...]
```

In the backgroundColor I had **5** F's '#FFFFF' instead of **6** '#FFFFFF'. And that's all. Sorry for the post. But I hope it can help somebody to not waste to much time with that issue.